# CSS transform on IE. Wrong size calculating

Tags: css, internet-explorer, transform

Why in IE and other browsers i have so different result?
IE calculate size of transformed element before transformation?

```css
  .foo {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: #0ff;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .bar {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #000;
    transform: scale(0.9) translate3d(-200px, -200px, 0);
    transform-origin: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    // margin-top:-200px;
    //rgin-left:-200px;
  }
```

```html
<div class='foo'>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Each browser has defined set of implementation. Try adding -50% to translate3d() or add vendor prefixes to css3 properties like -ms-transform

Comment: i try all of your variants. It's not work. Ie cant calculate correct size of element and create big scrollbars in parent